# NPM local package install

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

This might well be an ill conceived idea, but I have two react projects in version control, the first, let's call it A, contains a component I want to use in B. B therefore has a dependency on A declared in the package.json for B, as a file: ...path to project A.

The problem is that in order to build project B, the user needs to load both A and B onto their disk, then build A (this is a rollup build) and then build B. Because (I think) B depends on A with a file: reference, when installing A, NPM copies the whole directory including the node_modules folder of A under B. So you end up with `B/node_modules/A/node_modules`

I think the issue is that we are using the file system location of project A as both the source code location and the registry location if that makes sense. Perhaps we need to publish project A somewhere when it gets built and declare that location to be the dependency?

I hope that makes sense.

I looked at the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) and it seems like node_modules should always be ignored on an install if I am understanding the files section at all.

Comment: Separate node_modules for each project is normal. If you look at your A project's node_modules folder you will find something like `node_modules/react/node_modules` which would be react's own node_modules folder and then the dependencies react depends on will have their own `node_modules` folder - it's node_modules all the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common pattern for reusing components between projects is to move the component (or any piece of code that needs to be reused) outside of either A and B and create a standalone npm module containing that code/components.

Publish that module to either public or private npm repository depending on the sensitivity of the code and let both projects A and B install its own instance of that npm module. Otherwise these interdependencies will only cause you headaches in a long run.

Comment: I think I get this - what I'm confused with is how you would manage a local dependency - i.e. one that is declared as a file path rather than npm name.  Should the file location (which i think is the same here as if it were in a registry) only contain the built artifacts ? 

Is an NPM registry the only way to reuse modules ?

Comment: If you publish it as npm module, you wouldn't need to use file paths. And no, the path doesn't need to be the same. You can export everything from that npm module at the top level, no matter where in a folder structure it is located. And yes there are other options such as using git submodules but this is the easiest one to implement.

Comment: Is publishing your packages to a registry the only recommended way of reusing components ?

Comment: No it is definitely not the only way but in my opinion it is the easiest way to manage. The other options are, for example, using git submodules to use one project within another without copying the code https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules.